# load content while scrolling not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am writing a code which i scroll to the bottom of the window it loads another data with the help of php code.
   It loads the load_first.php file but not identifies the load_second.php file
  What problem in this code see this

```
  <?php $_SESSION['first']=1; if($_SESSION['first']==1) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            $('div#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="loading.gif">');
            var data="cachekey=" + $('.cachekey').val()+"&cachelocation="+ $('.cachelocation').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "load_data.php?last_msg_id="+ID,
                data:data,
                error:function(error)
                {
                    alert(error);
                },
                success: function(html){
                    if(html){
                        $(".message_box:last").after(data); 
                        $('div#last_msg_loader').hide();

                    }else{
                        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

</script>
<?php

include('load_first.php');

?>



<?php
}
else
{

  include('load_second.php');       

    }
    ?>  
    <div id="last_msg_loader"></div>
```

Actually this code is used to load the hotel list using xml api of expedia

Answer (score 0):

You've made an error in your if/else logic. First, you set:

```
$_SESSION['first']=1;
```

Then you follow directly with an if:

```
if($_SESSION['first']==1) {
```

Which means this is always true. The else clause:

```
else
{
   include('load_second.php');
}
```

therefore is *never* triggered. That's equally as writing:

```
if (TRUE) {
} else {
    # PHP will never go here.
}
```

So whatever you wanted to do with the `$_SESSION` variable, that is not the way to make it include `load_second.php` under any circumstances.

Comment: i change the $_session['first'] value to 2 after it goes to load_first.php therefore now if() condition changes to false so it goes to else condition

Comment: You might also need to replace `$_SESSION['first']=1;` with `if (!isset($_SESSION['first'])) { $_SESSION['first']=1; }` - so you don't set it again to 1 if it is already set.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that this condition will be true at bottom of scroll

```
  if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
```

use a console to log the values you will see they are never quite equal